# How can i get my code to print a character or string randomly?

Tags: c++, string, random, numbers, percentage

So I'm trying to test something out to see how rand() works in c++! I'm very new to c++ but I'm wondering how can I get the following code to print out either the letter B or A when the number 1 or 2 is generated?? the code ask if he wants to generate a letter, enter y for yes or n for no! then a letter generates but it seems to only generate the letter A?? any idea?

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <ctime>
    #include <cstdlib>

    using namespace std;

    int main(){
        char x;
        char d;
        cout << "generate random letter?(y/n)" << endl;
        cin >> x;
        if (x = 'y'){
    srand(time(NULL));

    int randNum = (rand() % 2) + 1;
    if (randNum = 1){
        d = 'A';
    }
    else {
        d = 'B';
    }
    cout << d << endl;
}
else{ return 0; }
system("pause");
    }
```

Comment: Hint:  On many local's and platforms, 'B' == 'A' + 1.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, isn't it on _all_ locales and platforms? I don't have the standard at hand, but I thought it was actually guaranteed that `'A'` through `'Z'` have successive character codes.

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

if (randNum == 1){

Comment: +1... and in `(x = 'y')` too.  `==` for equality testing, `=` for assignment.

Comment: A lot of C++-programmers will write their if-statements as `if(1 == randNum)` for exactly this reason: if you forget the double `==` there you will get a compiler error rather than an unexpected but correct result.

Answer (score 0):

In modern C++, [`rand()` is deprecated](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful), and other techniques based on e.g. `mt19937` Mersenne twister engine and `uniform_int_distrubtion` are used.

You may want to consider some code like this:

```
#include <iostream>     // For console output
#include <random>       // For pseudo-random number generators and distributions

int main()
{
    // Use random_device to generate a seed for Mersenne twister engine.
    std::random_device rd;    

    // Use Mersenne twister engine to generate pseudo-random numbers.
    std::mt19937 engine(rd());

    // "Filter" MT engine's output to generate pseudo-random integer values,
    // **uniformly distributed** on the closed interval [0, 1].  
    // (Note that the range is [inclusive, inclusive].)
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, 1);

    // Print 20 pseudo-random letters (A, B).
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    {
        // Generate pseudo-random number
        if (dist(engine) == 0)
        {
            std::cout << 'A';
        }
        else 
        {
            std::cout << 'B';
        }
        std::cout << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say:

```
if(randNum = 1)
```

you assign the value 1 to `randNum`, then check if it is `True`.  In C/C++ any non-zero number is `True`.  In this way you always enter the first part of the `if` statement and get an 'A'.

Instead if you say:

```
if(randNum == 1)
```

you are comparing `randNum` to `1` and will get the behavior you want.

Answer (score 0):

There's a much easier way to generate a random char.  Chars can be created from an ASCII code number since we know from uppercase A to lowercase Z is in the range of 65-122 (google ASCII table)

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 engine(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(65, 122);
char ascii_char = dist(engine);
std::cout << scii_char;
```

as a side note, std::uniform_int_distribution dist(65, 122) is inclusive, so it includes both 65 and 122.